# working with only one DB connection and transactions during whole webrequest

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, database-connection, castle-windsor

I have a new WebApi project that needs to talk to our DB (Oracle).

Decided to use an IoC framework. Final choise was Castle Windsor.

About all documentation I can find is using something like Entity Framework, Hibernate.

**But we want to use just a DB connection**. Not a whole framework. (LOTS of business logic in PL/SQL Stored Procedures/Functions).

**How do you manage this?**

What I currently have working:

```
container: HttpController -> Service   -> Repository  -> Connection
Lifestyle: PerWebRequest  -> Transient -> Transient   -> PerWebRequest
```

I have the separate Connection Container because I want the Service Containers to always use the same db connection during one webrequest. So if I understand correctly, the first repository that gets created gets a new connection, the others get the same.

the Connection Class looks like this:

```
public class MyConnection : IMyConnection
{
    String connectionString;
    private OracleConnection connection;

    public MyConnection()
    {
        RetrieveConnectionString();   
    }

    private void RetrieveConnectionString() { ... }

    public OracleConnection GetConnection()
    {
        if (this.connection == null)
        {
            OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection(this.connectionString);
            conn.Open();
            this.connection = conn;
        }

        return this.connection;
    }

    public void Dispose() //not being called
    {
        //this.connection.close()  ???
    }
}
```

It is used in a repository like this example:

```
public IEnumerable<items> Getlist()
{
    var result = new List<Registration>();

    using (OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand("FOO", _MyConnection.GetConnection())) // <--HERE 
    {
        cmd.BindByName = true;
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("result", OracleDbType.RefCursor, ParameterDirection.ReturnValue);

        using (OracleDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            if (reader.HasRows) { while (reader.Read()) {...} }
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

All fine for readonly access.

**But maybe I should better use some sort of Factory or Facility for this?**
I think Facility would be good only in case you want the connection to stay open forever.

**What about closing the connection?**
MyConnection.Dispose() does not get called. How else?

**What about control over transaction?**
Intermediate Commits, rollback to savepoint (oracle only?),.. to do stuff like this

```
public void SaveABC(ABC abc)
{

    _A_Repository.Save(abc.getA());
    //SAVEPOINT
    ..
    successB = _B_Repository.Save(abc.getB());
    ...
    successC = _C_Repository.Save(abc.getC());


    if (! (successA && successB))
        //rollbackToSavepoint()
}
```

As I understand it is desirable that a Service has no idea of the concept of a DB connection. So better not to have structure below?

```
container: HttpController -> Service   -> Repository  -> Connection
                                       -> Connection
Lifestyle: PerWebRequest  -> Transient -> Transient   -> PerWebRequest
                                       -> PerWebRequest
```

Some working example Project/tutorial/documentation/hints... about this would be great.

Comment: Please show how you are resolving and releasing components.